# Why Im getting response as 502 for sending email in production but it is working in development?

Tags: nodemailer, netlify, next.js13, app-router

I am building a portfolio in nextJs 13 with contact from that mainly depend on nodemailer, Ive created in side app router api/email/route.ts with following code:

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import Mail from "nodemailer/lib/mailer";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const { name, email, subject, message } = await request.json();

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_ACCOUNT,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_ACCOUNT,
    to: "example@gmail.com",
    subject: subject,
    text: `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nMessage: ${message}`,
  };

  // const sendMailPromise = () =>
  //   new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
  //     transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
  //       if (!err) {
  //         resolve("Email sent");
  //       } else {
  //         reject(err.message);
  //       }
  //     });
  //   });

  try {
    // await sendMailPromise();
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Email sent successfully" },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Failed to send email" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

In development locally the message is sent successfully but whenI deploy the project on netlify which is connecting it to my domain Im getting that message is failed to send wit bad gateway 502, I have allowed access for low level apps , tried different ports and configured ht`your text`tps tls/ssl on netlify , on the older version of next using pages it was working fine but now i am facing this problem Any suggestions?

I am expecting the email to be sent successfully on production.

Comment: What exactly is returning a 502? Your code returns a 500  on error. I don't know netlify, but I assume they have a sort of a proxy which then forwards the request to your service. 502 typically means, that the service behind the proxy can't be reached. Do you have any other request in that service taht work, so you can verify your service is at least running?  A typical error in such an environment is an erroneous deployment process which is missing something, so that for instance the environment variables are not picked up correctly.

Comment: @derpischer yes the only two codes I should get are 200 or 500 somehow I am getting 502, I will add a function that display a hello message with its code and see if it works.